# deciding $\beta$-equality of planar lambda terms

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, lambda-calculus, linear-logic

Mairson showed that the problem of computing the $\beta$-normal form of a linear lambda term (or equivalently, computing its principal type) is complete for polynomial time.

- Harry Mairson. [Linear lambda calculus and PTIME-completeness](http://www.cs.brandeis.edu/~mairson/Papers/jfp02.pdf). JFP 14(6), 2004.

In particular, he showed PTIME-hardness by reduction from the [circuit value problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_Value_Problem).

My question is about the restriction of the decision problem to linear lambda terms which are *planar* in the sense that they can be typed without using the exchange law (e.g., $B = \lambda x.\lambda y.\lambda z.x(yz)$ is planar, but $C = \lambda x.\lambda y.\lambda z.(xz)y$ is not). Is this an open problem? I would suspect that it has lower computational complexity, since Mairson's encoding of boolean circuits uses non-planarity in an essential way to distinguish "True" from "False".

I'm specifically interested in $\beta$-equality of planar lambda terms, but the problem is related to deciding equality of proofnets for non-commutative multiplicative linear logic, so I'd also be interested in any results in that direction.